# Problem with Date timestamp on Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, jestjs, timestamp

I have a function that set the date to UTC 0. Like this:

```js
const removeDateTimestamp = (date) => {
    return new Date(
        date.getUTCFullYear(),
        date.getUTCMonth(),
        date.getUTCDate(),
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    );
};
```

But the problem is when I use it. If I use on my console on the browser I get this result:

[image: use example]

```
Sat May 15 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
```

But when I run tests on Jest I got this other result:

```js
Received has type:  date
Received has value: 2021-05-14T22:00:00.000Z

it("removeDateTimestamp", () => {
expect(removeDateTimestamp(new Date(2021, 4, 16))).toMatch(
    /2021-05-16T00:00:00.000Z/i
  );
});
```

In the first example I have Sat May 15 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 when the passed day is 16, and in the second example with same day is 14.

I'm clearly overlooking something important but I don't see it.

Comment: BTW, when constructing a Date from year, month, etc. values, missing values are treated as zero (or 1 for the day) so `new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate()` will copy the date with the time parts set to zero. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` constructor interprets its arguments in **local** time. To get a `Date` instance from parts using UTC, use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) (which returns a milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value, so if you want a `Date` instance, you pass the result to `new Date`):

```
const removeDateTimestamp = (date) => {
    return new Date(
        Date.UTC(
            date.getUTCFullYear(),
            date.getUTCMonth(),
            date.getUTCDate(),
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )
    );
};
```

FWIW, here's another way to do the same thing you're doing above:

```
const removeDateTimestamp = (date) => {
    const newDate = new Date(+date); // Clone the date -- the `+` is important
                                     // on some JavaScript engines
    newDate.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return newDate;
};
```

I should also mention there's a way to do this with the [new Temporal API](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) that will be making its way into the standard library soon (already at Stage 3).

Comment: Belatedly *(sigh)* I realize there **must** be a dupetarget for this. I'm not immediately finding it (for instance, with [this](/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bjs%5d%20get%20date%20using%20utc)), but it seems really likely it's there. I have to get back to work (was naughty even posting this answer). If anyone finds it, please @ me so I can delete the above. Enric, please don't *accept* the answer above for a day or so, in case I'm right there's a pre-existing question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

T.J. has the detailed answer and I can't find a suitable duplicate so I'll post this as a simplification that fixes your issue.

Since ECMAScript days always have exactly 8.64e7 ms, you can just subtract the remainder after dividing by ms in one day, e.g.

```js
const getUTCTimeZero = (date) => new Date(date - date % 8.64e7);

console.log(getUTCTimeZero(new Date()))
```

The name *removeDateTimestamp* is a bit misleading as a timestamp is any string or number (or value perhaps) that represents a date or time. You seem to just want to set the time to zero, hence the different name.